# How can I filter a nested dictionary using LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

How can I filter a nested dictionary using LINQ in C#?

This is the dictionary that I'm starting with:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> countriesByContinentDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    {
        "Europe", 
        new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "0", "France" },
            { "1", "Germany"},
            { "2", "Switzerland" }
        } 
    },
    {
        "Asia",
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"zero", "India" },
            {"1", "Pakistan" },
            {"2", "Russia" }
        }
    },
    {
        "Africa",
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "0", "South Africa" },
            { "1", "Nigeria" },
            { "2", "Lybia"}
        }
    }
};
```

I'm trying to filter to countries that have the letter r.
This is what I'm trying to get it to look like after the filtering:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> countriesByContinentDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>
{
    {
        "Europe", 
        new Dictionary<string, string> {
            { "0", "France" },
            { "1", "Germany"},
            { "2", "Switzerland" }
        } 
    },
    {
        "Asia",
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
        }
    },
    {
        "Africa",
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "0", "South Africa" },
            { "1", "Nigeria" }
        }
    }
};
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> GetRecordsContainingSubStringWithLambda(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> originalNestedDictionary, string lambdaSubString)
{
    var filteredNestedDictionary = Enumerable.Range(0, originalNestedDictionary.Count)
        .Select(
                row => Enumerable.Range(0, originalNestedDictionary.ElementAt(row).Value.Count)
                .Select(col => originalNestedDictionary.ElementAt(row).Value.ElementAt(col))
                .Where(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value != null && keyValuePair.Value.Contains(lambdaSubString))
                .ToDictionary<string, string>(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value)
        ).ToDictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value);
    return filteredNestedDictionary;
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>, string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` directly, so there is no need for us to count indices. Instead, use `Select` to transform each item in the outer dictionary and `Where` to filter out inner items that do not match the filter, like so:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> GetRecordsContainingSubStringWithLambda(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> originalNestedDictionary, string lambdaSubString)
{
    return originalNestedDictionary.Select(outerPair => new KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, string>>(
        outerPair.Key,
        outerPair.Value
            .Where(innerPair => innerPair.Value != null && innerPair.Value.Contains(lambdaSubString))
            .ToDictionary(innerPair => innerPair.Key, innerPair => innerPair.Value)
    )).ToDictionary(outerPair => outerPair.Key, outerPair => outerPair.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This worked.
I made one change by replacing `innerPair.Key` to `innerPair.Value` to check if the value is `null`. If `innerPair.Value` is `null`, I receive an error.

Comment: @j.ruiz Ah yes, that would be a typo on my part. I'll edit the answer :)